# how to create new instance of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I'm having difficulties to create new instance from an object in javascript.
Try to read some answer, but still no luck.

```
var general_obj = {
    title : '',
    count : 0,
    details : [],
    status : 'OK'
}

function processData(input){
    var result = Object.create(general_obj);

    return result;
}
```

I wanted to create new instance from general_obj. I'm expecting the result would have the same structure as general_obj, whereby in my case the return become only

```
{}
```

instead of:

```
{
    title : '',
    count : 0,
    details : [],
    status : 'OK'
}
```

How can I achieve it ?

Comment: @Tushar editted. thanks

Comment: Your code works. It's just that the inherited properties are not logged. Try `console.log(result.count)` - it's `0`.

Comment: editted to be more specific.. sorry for incomplete code

Comment: I see you've reverted my conversion to snippet. I'm sorry if I didn't understand your intention.

Comment: Gerry - Depends what you mean by "instance". If you mean "copy" then `Object.create()` is the wrong method. If you mean "has a link to `general_obj` as its prototype" then that's what your code is doing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var general_obj = {
    title : '',
    count : 0,
    details : [],
    status : 'OK'
}

function processData(input){
    var result= (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(general_obj)));

    result.title = 'two';
    result.count = 10;
    result.details.push({
        "in-hand": 4,
        "warehouse": 6
    });
}
```

With json you can clone your object...

Comment: Note that this doesn't work if the object has methods. Or circular references.

Comment: I know, but in this case can be an easy way to approach

Comment: Thanks for this, but I don't understand. How come stringify and object and parse it again become a clone ?

Comment: There's no need to serialize and deserialize the object just so you get a new instance. These are fast operations, true, but compared to the alternatives - Object.assign, {...} syntax or just copying field by field in a for loop they're quite expensive and unwarranted.

Comment: You're welcome. Stringify make a string rappresentation of your object in Json. Next you pass this string in json.parse that create a js object from a Json string. The result is you have a new js object equal to the startin object. As @nnnnnn say, this approach work only if your starting obj is "flat", without methods or circular references. In that case you need to crate a class, and instantiate that class.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use `Object.assign({}, general_obj)` to create a new object, but with all fields copied from `general_obj`.

Keep in mind that this is a shallow copy however, and both the new instance and old one would be pointing to the same array through the `details` field.

---

The [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) function allows you to specify a *prototype* for the object that is created, which would result in similarish behaviour to what you want functionally, will result in you seeing the results you're observing.

Comment: yeah, I did try this assign, however the details [] keep increasing. I think because of "pointing to the same array" as you mentioned. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead:

```
function general_obj(title, count, details, status) {
    this.title = title;
    this.count = count;
    this.details = details;
    this.status = status;
}
```

Then instantiate with:

```
var result = new general_obj("", 0, [], "OK");
```

Comment: OK, and how would you create another instance based on the first one?

Comment: Is this expected from OP??

Comment: "I wanted to create new instance *from general_obj.* I'm expecting the result would have the same structure as general_obj..."